# How to create transparent background in ComponentActivity by jetpack compose

Tags: components, android-jetpack-compose, background-color, transparent

AttachmentPickerActivity it is an activity similar to dialog, half of the screen.
how to make AttachmentPickerActivity with trasparent background or something like that?

```
class AttachmentActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
            ){{
                    AttachmentLayout()

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```